# React Router: Pasar propiedades de un componente por medio del componente Link

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, api, react-router-dom

Buen día, estoy usando la librería de react router dom para lo que es una aplicación de las características de cada uno de los países del mundo, bueno el problema surge que cuando mando las propiedades que capturo del método fetchCountry y los mando a mi componente card, lo que me gustaría hacer si es posible o si hay una solución mas factible es que cuando le doy click al componente link este me mande al componente Descripcion.js y hay lo que quiero es mostrar todas las características de cada pais que vaya seleccionando

```
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

const Section1 = () => {

    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchCountry = async () => {
      fetch('https://restcountries.com/v2/lang/es')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(data);
      },
        (err) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(err);
        }
      );
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCountry();
      }, [])
      
      if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
      } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      } else {
        return (
          <section>
              <div className="flex flex-wrap p-1 m-10">
              { 
                items.map((item) => (
                  <div className="mr-8 mb-10" key={item.name} >
                  <Card {...item}/>
                  </div>
                ))
              }
              </div>
          </section>
          
    )
  }
}
export default Section1
```

Aquí se puede ver el componente section que lo que hace es llamar a la api de apicountry y los datos los mando a mi componente Card.js

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
const Card = ({ name, flag, population, region, capital, ...props }) => {

  return (
      <div className="w-280 h-full shadow-md rounded-md">
                    <Link to={`/description/${name}`} params={ props }>
          <img className="rounded-t-md w-full h-180" src={flag} alt="" />
                    </Link>
          <div className="p-2 mt-4 mb-10 mx-3">
              <h1 className="font-bold text-xl mb-3">{name}</h1>
              <h2 className="font-bold my-1">Population:<span className="font-normal ml-1">{population}</span></h2>
              <h2 className="font-bold my-1">Region:<span className="font-normal ml-1">{region}</span></h2>
              <h2 className="font-bold my-1">Capital:<span className="font-normal ml-1">{capital}</span></h2>
          </div>
      </div>
   )
};

export default Card;
```

Aquí en mi componente Card recibo las props e itero algunos datos como el nombre del pais, la region y la capital ahora bien en lo que es el componente link al darle click me dirige al componente description, pero ahora estando dentro de este componente quisiera agregar algunas de las descripciones que me incluye la api como el lenguaje, distancia, clima etc. pero no logro hacer que las props que recibo de card las pueda mandar por medio del componente link a mi componente descripcion y hay dentro poder iterar las propiedades faltantes, cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme seria de gran ayuda y la apreciaría mucho de antemano gracias

Comment: Si pudieras decirnos que versión de react-router estas usando, saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nótese la diferencia entre react-router V5 y V6

Se puede configurar el componente Link con [`link to: object`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object).

---

#### React Router V5

```
<Link to={{
      pathname:`/description/${name}`,
      state:"any type"
}}>
   mi link
</Link>
```

#### React Router V6

```
<Link to={`/description/${name}`} state:{"any type"}>
   mi link
</Link>
```

---

Luego, se recibe con el hook `useLocation`:

```
function myRouteComponent(){
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location.state);//"any type"

  return null;
}
```

Ahora bien, no se puede pasar `props` tal cual:

```
//react router v5
<Link to={`/description/${name}`} params={ props }>
//link to object invalido
 <Link to={{
          pathname:`/description/${name}`,
          state:props
    }}>
       mi link
 </Link>
```

Si se pasa `props` dentro del objeto, se obtendra el siguiente mensaje de error:

> DataCloneError: The object can not be cloned.

Entonces, se debe crear una estructura personalizada para enviar datos con el parametro `state` en `link to: object`.

---

#### React Router V5

```
  <Link to={{
              pathname:`/description/${name}`,
              state:{
                flag,
                population,
                region
              }
        }}>
           mi link
  </Link>
```

#### React Router V6

```
  <Link to={`/description/${name}`} 
        state:{{
                flag,
                population,
                region}
  }>
           mi link
  </Link>
```

---

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta en este caso pude resolver el problema en la version 5

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const navigate = useNavigate();

const toDescription=()=>{
  navigate(`/description/${name}`,
            {
              state:{
                name, 
                flag, 
                population, 
                region, 
                capital, 
                subregion,
                topLevelDomain,
                nativeName,
                currencies,
                languages, 
              }});
    }
```

Les dejo esta pequeña respuesta a la solucion que encontre para la version 6 en este caso en donde tengan sus variables y las vayan a madar a otro componente importen useNavigation, en este caso como pueden ver en la parte de navigate() coloco mi ruta a donde me va a dirigir y agrego el estado con los valores que quiero que mande a la otra ruta.

Para terminar lo que hice fue quitar el link que cubría mi componente img como puede ver en mi código y simplemente agregue un `onClick={toDescription}`, con eso me mandaba a mi componente `description` y con `useLocation()` ya iteraba los datos dentro del state

Comment: Vote por tu respuesta también, pero me queda una duda ¿Como aplicas `toDescription`, lo pones como valor de `to` en `Link`? saludos

Comment: Si mira, en este caso lo que yo hice fue quitar el link que cubría mi componente img como puede ver en mi código y simplemente agregue un onClick={toDescription}, con eso me mandaba a mi componente description y con useLocation() ya iteraba los datos dentro del state.